# From a field set, retrieve field's help text

Tags: apex, fieldsets, help

I have code that retrieves the fields in a field set.  I can retrieve the fields' labels.  However, I want to be able to retrieve the fields' help text.  Is there a way to do this?

```
Schema.FieldSet fs1 = Schema.SObjectType.Event_RSVP__c.fieldSets.getMap().get(selectedFieldSet);
        Map<String,String> fields;
        if(fs1 != null){
            fields = new Map<String,String>();
            List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fsm = fs1.getFields();
            for(Schema.FieldSetMember s : fsm){
                fields.put(s.getLabel(),s.getFieldPath() + '~' + s.getType());
}
        return fields;
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in doing this in Visualforce or Lightning?

Comment: I would like to do this in Lightning.